# PrintWriter over Socket OutputStream Causes Corruption/Loss of Data

Tags: java, character-encoding, io, network-programming, java-io

I'm trying to send a string from a server that has a default character encoding of *UTF-8* to a client that has a default character encoding of *windows-1252* via a **Socket** and **PrintWriter**.

When I run the client below, I'm not getting my original value of 141 back, despite even my attempts at converting the String using **CharsetDecoder**.

As a control test, I've tried running both these classes in Eclipse and enforcing that both use UTF-8 as their default encoding system via the dialogue below-- and I've observed that when both clients are using UTF-8, the output is successfully interpreted on the client's end.

**Update**: It looks like I'm able to stream bytes and recover the initial format, but in order to do so, I would have to know the encoding being used on the server. Is there not some kind of library that would be useful in this situation? I would much rather not be forced to transmit data in the form of byte arrays.

[image: Eclipse Dialog]

Server:

```
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

//Runs on a server with default character encoding of UTF-8
public class TestServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    PrintWriter writer = null;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {

        int x = 141;
        String s = "#" + (char)x;

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        writer = new PrintWriter(
                        (new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream())), true);

        System.out.println((int)s.charAt(1));
        writer.write(s);
    } catch(Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        writer.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
}
```

---

Client:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;

//Runs on a server with default character encoding of windows-1252
public class TestClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 5555);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

    String string = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println((int)string.charAt(1)); //prints 194 when it was 141 on the other end

    //Charset.defaultCharset returns windows-1252
    CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.defaultCharset().newDecoder();
    CharBuffer buffer = decoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(string.getBytes()));
    String convertedString = buffer.toString();

    System.out.println((int)convertedString.charAt(1)); //still prints 194

    String convertedString2 = new String(string.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println((int)convertedString2.charAt(1)); //prints 65533 ??

    s.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that there are OutputStreamWriter and InputStreamReader constructors that take character sets as a parameter. This is the solution I went with:

On the sender:

```
out = new PrintWriter(
   new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8")), true);
```

On the receiver:

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just `write()` a `byte[]` directly to the `OutputStream` and avoid the middle men, then  construct a new String on the client side from the `byte[]` returned. PrintWriter docs say:

> It does not contain methods for writing raw bytes, for which a program
>   should use unencoded byte streams.

In the new server code you'd have:

```
    bytep[] s = new String("#" + (char)x).getBytes();;
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    OutputStream writer = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
    System.out.println((int)s.charAt(1));
    writer.write(s);
```

On the client side, you'd create a ByteArrayInputStream and convert the bytes to a String:

```
byte[] return_data = null;
Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 5555);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int byte_read = bis.read();
while(byte_read != -1)
{
    baos.write(byte_read);
    byte_read = bis.read();

}

return_data = baos.toByteArray();
bis.close();
baos.close();   

String s = new String(return_data);
```

Comment: Hmm.. I saw that as an option but I was really trying to avoid it. Are there any other higher level OutputStream implementations I could use?

Comment: I think it's actually slightly less code to use the byte[] method. See the code sample I provided.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this would work but your solution doesn't provide a way to decode on the client's end without knowing the server's character encoding. Also, I'd really like a solution that doesn't require reading/writing bytes.

Comment: OK. I see what you want to do here. I'll look into it and report back.

Comment: ..and if it does have to involve reading/writing bytes, the solution would have to be able to read/write byte arrays of random sizes.

Comment: The more I look into it the more this seems like expected behavior. How can a client know from a string what encoding was used? I think you need to add some meta data to the payload so that the client can correctly decode it. Here's what I'd suggest. Create a class that implements Serializable that has two fields: a CharsetEncoder encoded byte array and a String with the charset name. Then use an ObjectOutputStream to serialize the object and write it to the stream. On the client side, use an ObjectInputStream and then create a new Charset object and CharsetDecoder on the byte array.

Comment: I agree. It certainly is the expected behavior. However, I'd be really surprised if there isn't some kind of library out there that can take care of a lot of the heavy lifting for this. I'm hoping someone will see this that's encountered this issue and found something of the sort.